# VBA Works Only On The First Time

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with VBA code, the code is to automatically add a row on a table with clients data if I entered a new client value to a table in a different sheet.

The weird thing is that the code works fine to add a new row and fill it with the needed data, but only for the first time, when I run it again it populate inly the first cell, and when I run it again it gives me error 400.

```
Sub Add_Quote_Data()
    Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table_object As ListObject
    Dim table_object_row As ListRow
    Set the_sheet = Sheets("QuotationsDB")
    Set table_list_object = the_sheet.ListObjects(1)
    Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

    table_object_row.Range(1, 2).Value = Range("K4").Value

    last_row_with_data = Range("K4").End(xlDown).Row
    last_row_with_data = last_row_with_data - 1

    the_sheet.Range("G" & last_row_with_data) = Range("K5").Value
    the_sheet.Range("H" & last_row_with_data) = Range("K6").Value
    the_sheet.Range("I" & last_row_with_data) = Now()

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you taking the trouble to work through all the definitions to get your listobject then abandon all of it to use `Range("K4").End(xlDown).Row` for your *last_row_with_data* assignment?

Comment: I Don't Know!, this is a formula that I found online and applied it

Comment: would you like to learn what the code means or are you simply looking for an adjustment that solves your current problem?

Comment: I need to adjust the code to solve my problem please.

Comment: Thank you very much You have resolved my issue with this question.